Displacement of an arbitrary point on a varibale pitch spring
Given an ideal variable pitch spring where the central section has a slightly larger pitch than the rest of the spring, is there a way to calculate the displacement of an arbitrary point on such spring?
Additionally, how can you calculate the total displacement/compression at which the smaller pitched sections are completely compressed?
